# Solr dataimport handler query

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I have following a dataimport handler:

```
<entity name="Categories" query="Select * From Categories">

  <field column="Name" name="categoryNgram"/>


    <entity name="CategorySynonyms" query="Select Synonym From CategorySynonyms Where CID='${Categories.Id}'">  

     <field column="Synonym" name="synonym"/>   

    </entity>

</entity>
```

The database tables have following values:

Categories

Id    Name

1     Category1

CategorySynonyms

CID

1      CategorySynonym1
1      CategorySynonym2

In the result is says Total Rows Fetched: 3

But when i select all from index *:* i only receive one row in the result:

Category1  SynonymCategory1

Is there something wrong with the syntax that makes it create only one document when is should create two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expected as the total number of rows fetched from database is 3 (1 from table **Categories** and 2 from **CategorySynonyms**).

The total number of document in solr is 1, as expected too:

```
Name:Category1,
Synonym: CategorySynonym1,CategorySynonym2
```

Perhaps you can try

```
<entity name="Categories" query="Select CID,Name,Synonym From Categories join CategorySynonyms on Id=CID">
  <field column="Name" name="categoryNgram"/>
  <field column="Synonym" name="synonym"/>   
</entity>
```

**Note:** you may have to verify the SQL query to make sure it returns an Id field, and two rows as you would expected.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why its expected to be only 1 document when 3 rows is fetched?

Comment: Glad to help! The sql query from top level <entity> corresponding to the number of documents, while the nested <entity> only expand the content of each document, rather than making new documents.  HIH